# libGDX JSON File Reading Error: Unable to Load Skin Resources

Tags: java, json, libgdx

Im trying to add a Slider into my settings menu and it´s not working at all.

Im initializing my Slider like this, in my Game class:

```
    public Skin sliderSkin;
    public void create() {
        sliderSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("assets/skins/slider-skin.json"));
```

The json looks like this (I have validated it)

```
{
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle": {
    "default-horizontal": {
      "background": "sliderBackground"
    }
  }
}
```

The file is located in:

```
- Project
-- assets
--- skins
---- slider-skin.json
```

I also have a `sliderBackground.png` located in the same folder as the json file.

I´m also getting this error:
`Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: sliderBackground`

Then, im getting this error while running the app:

`Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: assets/skins/slider-skin.json`

Ive tried changing the names of the files, the paths, the way Im initializing the Slider, and other things. I just want a slider to show, preferrably with my custom skin.

Comment: How are you loading the `sliderBackground.png`?

Answer (score 0):

A `Skin` expects to find the referenced images as `TextureRegion`s in a `TextureAtlas`, in your case I cannot see how you are loading the **sliderBackground.png** into an `TextureAtlas`.

You need to either have an *atlas* file called `slider-skin.atlas` in the same folder as your `slider-skin.json` (which contains a region called **sliderBackground** that has the image), or you need to manually load the atlas and pass it as the second argument to the `Skin` constructor.

The **libGDX** tool [Texture Packer](https://libgdx.com/wiki/tools/texture-packer) can be used to create the `TextureAtlas`, this is probably the most convenient way.

Or, if you want to just make it work for this one case you could try the following:

```
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas();
atlas.addRegion("sliderBackground", new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/skins/sliderBackground.png"))));
sliderSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("assets/skins/slider-skin.json", atlas));
```

But I would strongly recommend looking into the texture-packer and using that instead.